# Check which fonts are working

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I have used one google webfont i.e. "dancing script" and also added using @font-face, font-family but it is not appearing in the browser. I want to check that while viewing the site, which fonts is correctly uploaded or can be used to render properly. I mean to say that I want to check whether "dancing script" is uploaded properly in the browser or not.

Comment: can you give any examples of code? a live link? It's very hard to help you if you don't

Comment: <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
I have added by this way, so whenever te font-family dancingscript will be used it should render properly

Comment: If that's what you got from Google Web Fonts that probably works, It's your css and html markup we need to see, to see where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is the fiddle example.Have a look.You can understand everything!

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/GrvJ7/

```
span{
    font-size:30px;
    color:green;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}
```

you can add google font css file like as

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

OR

import in your existing css file like this;

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
```

Comment: I believe the OP has all this, but isn't seeing why the font isn't displaying in design

Comment: please share your code on online editor